# Momentum Indicators/Oscellators for Trading

Tags: trading, technical-analysis, momentum, investing, active-investing

The concept of momentum in trading is a bit weird to me.

It seems to me to be measuring a first derivative or first difference of price, or something in that ballpark depending on the exact formulae used.  I would describe this as the velocity of a security's price.  I would expect momentum to require some concept of mass, and that momentum would be given by mass $*$ velocity.

Is there a notion of mass (perhaps related to trading volume) in finance?  If not, is trading momentum just the quantity that one would expect to be called velocity?  If so, why is it called momentum instead of velocity?

Comment: You're analogy is interesting, but I think it's called "momentum" in a colloquial sense. Like, "things which start moving keep moving" are things that have momentum. If I were to go with your analogy though, I feel that volume would be an interesting analogue to mass, though!

Comment: In Finance the definition of momentum is different than in physics. Momentum is just the price change over an agreed length of time. So for example some people look at "6 month momentum" others follow "1 year momentum". It is important to know what definition someone is using, it varies. In Finance neither mass nor velocity are well defined, let alone the product.